# Connection refused with selenium after clicking an element

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'll try to explain my problem as shortly and precisely as possible.

I'm trying to automate this website in order to fullfill the survey automatically: https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=J_MxGtETnkCJtoTI3pL1UnkYW0ynf4dLv0B_tcadw1NUNklaWkJPSjk2WEM0UTBBS1FIS1MwU05LQy4u

I have a major problem. Whenever webdriver tries to click the 'Sélectionnez votre réponse' case, I get several errors:

1. *ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused*
2. *urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe51e4a5d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused*
3. *urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=61616): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/84d1bcb3f29dcea5ebc17515f7006576/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe51e4a5d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))*

In order to solve this I tried to open up the hidden tab doing this:

Since the HTML is as is: `<div aria-describedby="Select_0_placeholder" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Sélectionnez votre réponse" class="office-form-question-dropdown [the rest is not important]`

I tried to modify the value of `aria-expanded` with js in order to make the invisible tab 'roll down'. This is my string of code:

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('Select_0').aria-expanded = true ;");`

But it gets me this error :
javascript error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I couldn't manage to find a solution to this problem, and to be honest I don't know if it will even solve my biggest problem (which is that I get a 'connection refused' when I try to click the element).

Please help me solve this problem, I really have no clue why I'm getting disconnected from the website and why it doesn't roll down the tab.

Thanks!

Comment: Where can we find the `Sélectionnez votre réponse` element?

Comment: It's in the survey, it's a clickable element that rolls down a selection menu, maybe it's in english for you

Answer (score 0):

This should click the select_0_placeholder and select the first li tag. I'm not sure
what you want to selected.

```
driver.get("https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=J_MxGtETnkCJtoTI3pL1UnkYW0ynf4dLv0B_tcadw1NUNklaWkJPSjk2WEM0UTBBS1FIS1MwU05LQy4u")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Next']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Select_0_placeholder"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='select-option-menu-container']/li[1]"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it gets a timeout error because the element is not clickable. Isn't there a way to make js change the value of aria-expanded from "false" to "true"? I tried the driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('Select_0').aria-expanded = 'true' ;"); method but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using xpath //div[@aria-describedby='Select_0_placeholder'] instead

Comment: Yes, it does work now, but I get the error I described in the question, I get a connection refused. It happens everytie I make selenium click on the element. I don't know how to solve this problem. Isn't there a way to make js change the value of aria-expanded from "false" to "true"?